# is there a setting in php.ini that could be limiting the number of concurrent users accessing my site?

Tags: php, ini

Is there a setting in php.ini that could be limiting the number of concurrent users accessing my site? The site is built on the codeigniter framework running on ISS 7.5. We are using sqlsrv 2005 for the DB.

Comment: PHP isn't even aware of the existence of other connections, concurrent or otherwise; so any limitation of this kind would normally be configured in the web server or in a firewall - typically for preventing something like a DoS flood attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php.ini` isn't the right place to look for this. You can define a max connections setting within the `<limits>` element of the `<site>` settings (along with the amount of bandwidth or the connection time-out for client requests to a site).

Sample config:

```
<sites>
    <site name="My Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/"
            physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http"
            bindingInformation="*:80:" />
        </bindings>
        <limits maxBandwidth="65536" maxConnections="1024"
         connectionTimeout="00:01:00" />
    </site>
</sites>
```

Comment: where would I find this?

Comment: [Here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits#006).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the php.ini does not limit the number of concurrent users.

You should take a look at your ISS and database configurations. They both probably limit concurrent connections.